# How to force IntelliJ to use a different home folder

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a computer with two hard drives. In the first one, an SSD disk, I have Windows partition (C) and on the second one (D), a raid volume, I install all the programs. I also moved my user folders (desktop, documents, downloads, pictures and videos) to `D:/Users/David`.

After installing IntelliJ Idea on `D:/Program Filles(x86)` a .IntelliJIdea13 directory appeared on `D:/Users/David`. No problem with this as all was working nice. Then I installed Scala plugin, created a new SBT project and build it. After this, the .sbt directory used by SBT was in `C:/Users/David/.sbt` but the references to the libraries in my project are pointing to `D:/Users/David/.sbt`. The question is, how can I force IntelliJ Idea or Scala plugin to download the libraries to `D:/Users/David.sbt`?

Comment: Is the raid from normal HDDs? If so, then why would you want to use that instead of SSD? Also, look into idea.properties...

Comment: Yes, normal HDDs and I use it mainly because the SSD only have 50GB and I read that is not a good idea to write too much in a SSD. I also read that file but there isn't anything related with SBT.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it is only for changing .IntelliJIdea13 directory.

Comment: btw writing to ssd is an excellent idea, unless you need to write more than ~100GB/day (rough number, depending on SSD, and on desire to have SSD forever).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this can be a solution, you can change the HOME folder of Intellij IDEA. Look for the folder where the idea executable is. In Linux I have on

```
 ~/applications/idea13/bin
```

On Windows you can check the properties of the menu item. There should be file **idea.properties** that contains the home folder location of the idea files.

You can find more information [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348963-Changing-IDE-default-directories-used-for-config-plugins-and-caches-storage) that describe more details:

> Locations can be changed by editing the following file:
>   IDE_HOME\bin\idea.properties
>
> Follow the comments in idea.properties file to change the defaults,
>   make sure to un-comment the lines defining these properties:
>   idea.config.path 
>   idea.system.path 
>   idea.plugins.path 
>   idea.log.path

On the other hand you can change the location of your project to D:/Users/David. you should also have a look inside the project folder, there should be a .idea folder with has a library directory. They contains the location of the libs used in the project with their paths.

Comment: To add to @dawex's answer, on Windows, it is `{IdeaInstallDir}/bin/idea.properties` file. You will want uncomment and set the `idea.config.path` and the `idea.system.path` properties. Keep in mind you will need to modify this file anytime you do a fresh install.

Comment: I was trying to change the SBT directory path but this is way easier. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to update ${user.home} in this file? It points to a shared drive which is incorrect and I have to change it.

Answer (score 7):

As dawez allready answered, you should edit **idea.properties** to set config, system, plugins and log paths.

But if you want to change the user.home path, then you must edit **idea.exe.vmoptions** file. Just add the following at the end of the file:

```
-Duser.home=your_new_user_home_path
```

If you use *idea64.exe* then you should edit **idea64.exe.vmoptions** file.

Comment: The vmoptions file that you should change is your custom one rather than the install directory one. In that way the changes you make are not overridden when you update IntelliJ. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57763571/3059685

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains had added complete set of features to support such a case and this is described here:

[Changing IDE default directories used for config, plugins, and caches storage](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207240985-Changing-IDE-default-directories-used-for-config-plugins-and-caches-storage)