# Force IntelliJ to use another Home Directory?

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, ide

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449737/how-to-force-intellij-to-use-a-different-home-folder)... it does not answer the question.

I would like to have IntelliJ use another location for all of my project files.  Currently, it goes to c:\users\ as a default project location.

I want to change that to c:\git.

I tried to change the "Start in" link properties, to no avail.

I don't want to force all of the configuration (ie: the .IdeaIC15 folder) to be relocated, I just want it to go to c:\git when I click "Open project".

Comment: My IntelliJ remembers where was the last project created and treats that folder as default.

Comment: Where does it "remember" the last location?

Comment: I don't know. But when I invoke the open dialog again, it goes to the last parent directory.

Comment: In IntelliJ2019.3 it remembers the last location in the `file.chooser.recent.files` property in the _.IdeaIC2019.3/config/options/other.xml_ file

Answer (score 2):

To change the directory where project files are located to `C:\git`:

1. Select **Help->Edit Custom VM Options...**
2. Add the following line to the end of the file that comes up in the editor (*):

   `-Duser.home=C:\git`
3. Restart IntelliJ.

(*) The file that comes up in the editor will either be `idea64.exe.vmoptions` or `idea.exe.vmoptions`.

**Notes**:

- This will update/create a *.vmoptions* file in your *config* directory. It does not modify the vmoptions file in your install directory.
- The above steps do **not** change the default directory that is used
  when cloning git repositories. This is the directory that is used in
  the **File->New->Project from Version Control->Git** window. You
  still need to set that directory to `C:\git` **and** clone one remote repo
  into `C:\git`. Once you have done that IntelliJ remembers the directory and
  uses it for subsequent clones.

Answer (score 1):

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207240985-Changing-IDE-default-directories-used-for-config-plugins-and-caches-storage

Locations can be changed by editing the following file:

IDE_HOME\bin\idea.properties

Follow the comments in idea.properties file to change the defaults, make sure to un-comment the lines defining these properties:

```
idea.config.path
idea.system.path
idea.plugins.path
idea.log.path
```